# Alternative to Outlook 2007 to sync with BlackBerry?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, software-rec, blackberry

I installed Outlook (2007) since it's the most used PIM that can sync with a BlackBerry, but I find its UI ugly, and the different dialogs contain way too much items for my use.

Does someone know of a good alternative? Ideally, it should be able to sync with BlackBerry directly, but I can live with one that goes through Outlook for synchronization.

FWIW, I prefer desktop applications to eg. Google apps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to Blackberry sync, you're pretty much stuck with either Outloook or Lotus Notes (ugh). As far as I know, there is no sync support for Thunderbird.

It may or may not be what you are looking for, but the solution I was using with my BB was to run Google Sync to sync Calendar and contacts and use Blackberry push service to receive my emails from various accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll stick to Outlook until I find a desktop-based alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/KB14730